# Stop iwctl from automatically connecting to network

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, gnome

I have recently installed arch linux along with gnome DE. During installation I used iwctl command to connect to wifi. But after installing the DE, I no longer need it.

But on every boot, it automatically connects to wifi network, and hence I am not able to use the gnome settings to connect to wifi. I have to open terminal and open iwctl and then use the disconnect command `station wlan0 disconnect`. After this only I am able to switch networks from the gnome settings.

How do I stop iwctl from connecting to the network everytime on a boot? Should I disable iwd service, since iwctl comes under that? Or would that cause more trouble.

Link to [iwd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Iwd) page on archwiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to forget the network from iwctl.

Just run run `iwctl`

and then run `known-networks list`, to list the known networks to iwctl. And then use `known-networks SSID forget` where SSID is the SSID is the SSID of a network you are trying to forget

Answer (score 7):

You might want to use the command `known-networks <Network-Name> set-property AutoConnect no` from within `iwctl`.

Comment: You can also add `AutoConnect=false` under a `[Settings]` category in `/var/lib/iwd/<network name>.psk` if you prefer that option.